# flextable format different rows differently flextable

Tags: r, flextable

is it possible to dynamically format the number of decimals on a double column in a flextable dependant on the name of the row?

I have

```
df = data.frame(name = LETTERS[1:2], col1 = 1:2, col2 = 11:12)
df %>% flextable()
```

[image]

I would like to see `1 decimal place if name ==A`, and `2 decimal places if name ==B`

so col1 would end up as `1.0 and 2.00` and col2 would end up as `11.0 and 12.00`

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result using `colformat_double` by passing a condition to the `i` argument, e.g. `i = ~name=="A"` will select the `"A"` rows. However, you have to make sure that your columns are indeed of type `double`. It will not work if the columns are `integer`s. That's why added an additional `mutate` step.

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(name = LETTERS[1:2], col1 = 1:2, col2 = 11:12)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.numeric)) %>%
  flextable() %>%
  colformat_double(i = ~name=="A", digits = 1) %>%
  colformat_double(i = ~name=="B", digits = 2)
```

[image]